# Lookup Field in Flows does not give the exact Name of user

Tags: visual-workflow, account-teams

My Requirement is I have to create a custom button which allows certain users to add Account Key Member in Account Related list.
I am trying to achieve this requirement by creating visual flows.As per Salesforce Standard Functionlity,I can not directly add lookup field in flows.
'Team member' which is a standard lookup field on Account Team Member Object,I create the same field in my flows and trying to get the exact user that I want to add as Accoutn Team Member.

I have designed the flows as follow:

[image]
Add Account Team Member:
[image]
Matching Records:
[image]
Dynamic Choice:
[image]
Selected Team Member:
[image]

But when I search for exact user that I want to display,it does not give me correct result.It gives me random result where the user that i want to search is not present in serach result.
Can somebody tell me what I am missing in Dynamic Choice Criteria?

Expection:once it will give me exact user name that i want to add as team member,I have to add rest of fields which is same as Accoutn team member and in the end it creates 'Account Team Member' record in related list of account via flows.

Comment: I think varTeamMemberName is not being set. Can you have your dynamic choice filter on the screen input field?  So filter on name contains {screenInputFieldName}. Else I believe you need an assignment to set varTeamMemberName to the value entered in the screen input field.

Comment: @gorav I have assigned the screen input field value to the field name and it gives me exact result now.We can also use assignment in which we can assign it to variable but no need to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your varTeamMemberName is a variable rather than the unique name of the Team Member name field on the Add Account Team Member screen then it will not have a value assigned, you need to add an assignment step.

The following images show how this would work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

To capture a picklist value using the values from the object picklist create a new Choice field and select picklist choice.

[image]

Then on the dialogue give it a unique name and select the picklist type (normal or multi-select), object and picklist you require. It will then let you access the values from the object at runtime.

[image: set picklist choice values]

Comment: Yes it works,.Thanks.One question I am having trouble to add picklist field value of field 'Account Access' which is present on 'AccountTeam Member' object.How can add the field in my screen..when i try to add Picklist choice in my dropdown list field,it throws an error."Bad Values for Restricted Picklist field."

Comment: Are you just retrieving the value from the existing record or do you want to set it on the flow screen?

Comment: I want to set picklist field value on screen so that i can create Account Team Member record via flows.

Comment: ok can add that into the answer.

Comment: Have u added picklist field value into ur answer?

Comment: Added now as I needed to grab screenshots.

Comment: Thanks it works for few picklist field.In my case on 'AccountTeamMember' object,I can add MemberRole Picklist field on my flows but can not add other Picklist field such as Accoutn Access,ContactAccess,OpportunityAccess,CaseAccess.You can try to add any of those fields in your flows.When u try to save it,it will throws an error.Not sure why? but thanks for the info.

Comment: Dhanajay please raise that as a separate question.